# Rails: form_for with submodel for user selecting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, form-for

For example, I have a `product` model. Each product has one `type` named `ProductType`. Now I want to create product.

Here is my simple form using slim:

```
= form_for @product, url: product_path, :html => {:method => post} do f
  = f.label :name
  = f.text_field :name
  = f.submit 'Create'
```

I want in this form, there is a drop-down list that list all type of product (load from `ProductType`) and user can choose one. How can I do this in rails (using `form_for`)

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`collection_select` is built for exactly this purpose.

Assuming `ProductType` has a `name` attribute, try

```
= form_for @product, url: product_path, :html => {:method => post} do f
  = f.label :name
  = f.text_field :name

  # collection_select creates a select box with the options set from the collection
  = f.label :type
  = f.collection_select :type, ProductType.all, :name, :id

  = f.submit 'Create'
```

Review the documentation:
http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.7/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_select

Comment: thanks so much. I have a little more question. in my product, i have two field: `type_id` and `type_name` (for preventing query `ProductType` table). How can I make `form_for` understand and send both `id` and `name` from `ProductType` to `Product` table fields respectively. (so I don't need to query again `ProductType` for getting name from id). thanks

Comment: I recommend posting this as as separate question so that everyone can benefit from it. In short, I recommend using a `before_save` callback in the `Product` model to set the `name`. Happy to elaborate on a separate post if you'd like

Comment: and one more thing. As I read in document, they use something such as: `collection_select(:post, :author_id, Author.all, :id, :name_with_initial, prompt: true)`. so in my case it should be: `f.collection_select :product, :type, ProductType.all, :name, :id`. But when I do this, I meet error: `undefined method `merge' for :name:Symbol`. thanks

Comment: There are two forms of the `collection_select` method, one called by itself and one called within a `form_for`. When you call `f.collection_select` within a `form_for` (like in your case), you can omit the first parameter `:product` because the `@product` is already passed in to the `form_for`

Comment: Can you tell me `f.collection_select` How can I make this same line with label. I have put label and `f.collection_select` in same div. but look like it doesn't work

Comment: If you have another question it's best to ask it on a separate post so everyone can benefit from the answer. To make the label appear on the same line, you need to work with the CSS. Happy to elaborate on a new post if you'd like. Good luck!